# $.ajax's strange behaviour on Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

Does anyone know if `$.ajax` eventually calls `XHR.open()` on Safari? I've tried overriding `XHR.open()` and calling `$.ajax()`, but it doesn't break inside the overriding `XHR.open()`. It works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. Does `$.ajax` behave differently on Safari?

For instance:

```
window.XMLHttpRequest = class MyFakeXHR extends XMLHttpRequest {
  open(method, url, ...args) {
      console.log("XHR.open() called");
      return super.open(method, url, ...args);
  }
};

$.ajax('https://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

It prints in Chrome/Firefox, but not in Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of problems with ajax in safari, an open issue from the last 2 years have been reported here regarding [Cross Domain Requests](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112471).

if you want to investigate further, there is this [post](https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/545359-xmlhttprequest-wont-open-safari) regarding xhr request that won't open in safari, similar to your problem.

The bottom line is that safari and IE, mostly in their early versions, produce a lot of issues, ajax calls issues included.

Comment: But I'm calling `$.ajax('https://www.stackoverflow.com')` on `stackoverflow.com`. If it doesn't call `XHR.open()`, what does it call to initialise the request? Also, the link you gave is dated 2006.

Comment: It is still up to date and as I said, there are a lot of problems concerning safari and ajax, I would suggest asking this question at the safari official forums instead :)